# No route matches - missing required key

Tags: ruby-on-rails

trying to create a videogame review website for practice. ran into this problem of missing key / no route matches.

below are my Games, and Reviews contrller. Review is nested inside Games.

Many thanks in advance :)

edit:

the error is:

No route matches {:action=>"update", :controller=>"reviews", :game_id=>3, :id=>nil} missing required keys: [:id]

full error code below:

No route matches {:action=>"update", :controller=>"reviews", :game_id=>3, :id=>nil} missing required keys: [:id]

```
actionpack (4.2.1) lib/action_dispatch/journey/formatter.rb:46:in `generate'
actionpack (4.2.1) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:727:in `generate'
actionpack (4.2.1) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:758:in `generate'
actionpack (4.2.1) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:801:in `url_for'
actionpack (4.2.1) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:280:in `call'
actionpack (4.2.1) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:223:in `call'
actionpack (4.2.1) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:345:in `block (2 levels) in define_url_helper'
app/views/games/show.html.erb:22:in `block in _app_views_games_show_html_erb___707335474_75793908'
c:in `each'
c:in `each'
app/views/games/show.html.erb:20:in `_app_views_games_show_html_erb___707335474_75793908'
actionview (4.2.1) lib/action_view/template.rb:145:in `block in render'
activesupport (4.2.1) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:166:in `instrument'
actionview (4.2.1) lib/action_view/template.rb:333:in `instrument'
actionview (4.2.1) lib/action_view/template.rb:143:in `render'
actionview (4.2.1) lib/action_view/renderer/template_renderer.rb:54:in `block (2 levels) in render_template'
actionview (4.2.1) lib/action_view/renderer/abstract_renderer.rb:39:in `block in instrument'
activesupport (4.2.1) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:164:in `block in instrument'
activesupport (4.2.1) lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:20:in `instrument'
activesupport (4.2.1) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:164:in `instrument'
actionview (4.2.1) lib/action_view/renderer/abstract_renderer.rb:39:in `instrument'
actionview (4.2.1) lib/action_view/renderer/template_renderer.rb:53:in `block in render_template'
actionview (4.2.1) lib/action_view/renderer/template_renderer.rb:61:in `render_with_layout'
actionview (4.2.1) lib/action_view/renderer/template_renderer.rb:52:in `render_template'
actionview (4.2.1) lib/action_view/renderer/template_renderer.rb:14:in `render'
actionview (4.2.1) lib/action_view/renderer/renderer.rb:42:in `render_template'
actionview (4.2.1) lib/action_view/renderer/renderer.rb:23:in `render'
actionview (4.2.1) lib/action_view/rendering.rb:100:in `_render_template'
actionpack (4.2.1) lib/action_controller/metal/streaming.rb:217:in `_render_template'
actionview (4.2.1) lib/action_view/rendering.rb:83:in `render_to_body'
actionpack (4.2.1) lib/action_controller/metal/rendering.rb:32:in `render_to_body'
actionpack (4.2.1) lib/action_controller/metal/renderers.rb:37:in `render_to_body'
actionpack (4.2.1) lib/abstract_controller/rendering.rb:25:in `render'
actionpack (4.2.1) lib/action_controller/metal/rendering.rb:16:in `render'
actionpack (4.2.1) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:44:in `block (2 levels) in render'
activesupport (4.2.1) lib/active_support/core_ext/benchmark.rb:12:in `block in ms'
c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/2.1.0/benchmark.rb:294:in `realtime'
activesupport (4.2.1) lib/active_support/core_ext/benchmark.rb:12:in `ms'
actionpack (4.2.1) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:44:in `block in render'
actionpack (4.2.1) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:87:in `cleanup_view_runtime'
activerecord (4.2.1) lib/active_record/railties/controller_runtime.rb:25:in `cleanup_view_runtime'
actionpack (4.2.1) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:43:in `render'
actionpack (4.2.1) lib/action_controller/metal/implicit_render.rb:10:in `default_render'
actionpack (4.2.1) lib/action_controller/metal/implicit_render.rb:5:in `send_action'
actionpack (4.2.1) lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:198:in `process_action'
actionpack (4.2.1) lib/action_controller/metal/rendering.rb:10:in `process_action'
actionpack (4.2.1) lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb:20:in `block in process_action'
activesupport (4.2.1) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:117:in `call'
activesupport (4.2.1) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:117:in `call'
activesupport (4.2.1) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:555:in `block (2 levels) in compile'
activesupport (4.2.1) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:505:in `call'
activesupport (4.2.1) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:505:in `call'
activesupport (4.2.1) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:92:in `_run_callbacks'
activesupport (4.2.1) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:776:in `_run_process_action_callbacks'
activesupport (4.2.1) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:81:in `run_callbacks'
actionpack (4.2.1) lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb:19:in `process_action'
actionpack (4.2.1) lib/action_controller/metal/rescue.rb:29:in `process_action'
actionpack (4.2.1) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:32:in `block in process_action'
activesupport (4.2.1) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:164:in `block in instrument'
activesupport (4.2.1) lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:20:in `instrument'
activesupport (4.2.1) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:164:in `instrument'
actionpack (4.2.1) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:30:in `process_action'
actionpack (4.2.1) lib/action_controller/metal/params_wrapper.rb:250:in `process_action'
activerecord (4.2.1) lib/active_record/railties/controller_runtime.rb:18:in `process_action'
actionpack (4.2.1) lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:137:in `process'
actionview (4.2.1) lib/action_view/rendering.rb:30:in `process'
actionpack (4.2.1) lib/action_controller/metal.rb:196:in `dispatch'
actionpack (4.2.1) lib/action_controller/metal/rack_delegation.rb:13:in `dispatch'
actionpack (4.2.1) lib/action_controller/metal.rb:237:in `block in action'
actionpack (4.2.1) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:74:in `call'
actionpack (4.2.1) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:74:in `dispatch'
actionpack (4.2.1) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:43:in `serve'
actionpack (4.2.1) lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:43:in `block in serve'
actionpack (4.2.1) lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:30:in `each'
actionpack (4.2.1) lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:30:in `serve'
actionpack (4.2.1) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:819:in `call'
warden (1.2.3) lib/warden/manager.rb:35:in `block in call'
warden (1.2.3) lib/warden/manager.rb:34:in `catch'
warden (1.2.3) lib/warden/manager.rb:34:in `call'
rack (1.6.4) lib/rack/etag.rb:24:in `call'
rack (1.6.4) lib/rack/conditionalget.rb:25:in `call'
rack (1.6.4) lib/rack/head.rb:13:in `call'
actionpack (4.2.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/params_parser.rb:27:in `call'
actionpack (4.2.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/flash.rb:260:in `call'
rack (1.6.4) lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:225:in `context'
rack (1.6.4) lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:220:in `call'
actionpack (4.2.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/cookies.rb:560:in `call'
activerecord (4.2.1) lib/active_record/query_cache.rb:36:in `call'
activerecord (4.2.1) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:649:in `call'
activerecord (4.2.1) lib/active_record/migration.rb:378:in `call'
actionpack (4.2.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:29:in `block in call'
activesupport (4.2.1) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:88:in `call'
activesupport (4.2.1) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:88:in `_run_callbacks'
activesupport (4.2.1) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:776:in `_run_call_callbacks'
activesupport (4.2.1) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:81:in `run_callbacks'
actionpack (4.2.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:27:in `call'
actionpack (4.2.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/reloader.rb:73:in `call'
actionpack (4.2.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/remote_ip.rb:78:in `call'
actionpack (4.2.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/debug_exceptions.rb:17:in `call'
web-console (2.1.3) lib/web_console/middleware.rb:37:in `call'
actionpack (4.2.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:30:in `call'
railties (4.2.1) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:38:in `call_app'
railties (4.2.1) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:20:in `block in call'
activesupport (4.2.1) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:68:in `block in tagged'
activesupport (4.2.1) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:26:in `tagged'
activesupport (4.2.1) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:68:in `tagged'
railties (4.2.1) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:20:in `call'
actionpack (4.2.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/request_id.rb:21:in `call'
rack (1.6.4) lib/rack/methodoverride.rb:22:in `call'
rack (1.6.4) lib/rack/runtime.rb:18:in `call'
activesupport (4.2.1) lib/active_support/cache/strategy/local_cache_middleware.rb:28:in `call'
rack (1.6.4) lib/rack/lock.rb:17:in `call'
actionpack (4.2.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/static.rb:113:in `call'
rack (1.6.4) lib/rack/sendfile.rb:113:in `call'
railties (4.2.1) lib/rails/engine.rb:518:in `call'
railties (4.2.1) lib/rails/application.rb:164:in `call'
rack (1.6.4) lib/rack/lock.rb:17:in `call'
rack (1.6.4) lib/rack/content_length.rb:15:in `call'
rack (1.6.4) lib/rack/handler/webrick.rb:88:in `service'
c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/2.1.0/webrick/httpserver.rb:138:in `service'
c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/2.1.0/webrick/httpserver.rb:94:in `run'
c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/2.1.0/webrick/server.rb:295:in `block in start_thread'
```

** also having problems with the Show view. i think its the delete action
*** also can you take a look at my form partial for the review submission? i'm basically trying to render have the text area rendered in the Show view, then once submited, appear below the text area.

I can add reviews and save them, but once submitted, I get an error. i go to rails console, and see that the reviews are saved -- but just curious if my logic is any good.

Routes.rb

```
  resources :games do
      resources :reviews, except: [:show, :index]
    end
```

Games_controller.rb

```
class GamesController < ApplicationController

    before_action :set_game, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

    def index
        @games = Game.all
    end

    def show
        @reviews = Review.where(game_id: @game.id)
    end

    def create
        @game = Game.new(game_params)
        @game.save
        redirect_to @game
    end

    def new
        @game = Game.new
        set_platforms
        set_genres
    end

    def edit
        @platforms = Platform.order(:system)
        set_platforms
        set_genres
    end

    def update
        @game.update(game_params)
        redirect_to @game
    end

    def destroy
        @game.destroy
        redirect_to action: :index
    end

private

    def game_params
        params.require(:game).permit(:title, :image, :release_date, :genre_id, :platform_id)
    end

    def set_game
        @game = Game.find(params[:id])
    end

    def set_platforms
        @platforms = Platform.order(:system)
    end

    def set_genres
        @genres = Genre.order(:category)
    end

end
```

Reviews_controller.rb

```
class ReviewsController < ApplicationController

    before_action :authenticate_user!, :set_review, only: [:show, :update, :edit, :destroy]
    before_action :set_game

    def index
    end

    def show
    end

    def new
        @review = Review.new
    end

    def create
        @review = Review.new(review_params)
        @review.user_id = current_user.id
        @review.game_id = @game.id
        @review.save
    end

    def edit
        @review.update(review.params)
    end

    def destroy
        @review.destroy
        redirect_to games_path
    end

    private

    def review_params
        params.require(:review).permit(:comment)
    end

    def set_review
        @review = Review.find(params[:id])
    end

    def set_game
        @game = Game.find(params[:game_id])
    end
end
```

show.html.erb

```
<p><%= link_to "<< Home", games_path %></p>
<span><%= link_to "Edit", edit_game_path %></span>
<span><%= link_to "Delete", game_path(@game), method: :delete %></span>

<p><%= link_to "Add Steelbook", new_steelbook_path %></p>

<div class="game_summary">
    <h2><%= @game.title %></h2>
    <%= image_tag @game.image %>
    <p>Release Date: <%= @game.release_date %> </p>
        <p>Genre: <%= @game.genre_id %> </p>
    <p>Platforms: <%= @game.platform_id %></p>
</div>

<div class="game_review submit">
    <%= render "review" %>
</div>

<% @reviews.each do |review| %>
    <p><%= review.comment %></p>
    <p><%= link_to "delete comment", game_review_path(review.game_id), method: :delete  %></p>
    <p><%= review.game_id %></p>
<% end %>
```

Form partial

```
<%= form_for [@game, @reviews.new] do |r| %>

    <h3>Review this game</h3>

    <p>
        <%= r.text_area :comment %>
    </p>

    <p>
        <%= r.hidden_field :game_id, value: @game.id %>
    <p>

    <%= r.submit %>

<% end %>
```

Comment: Please update your post with complete error log.

Comment: hi guys, sorry about that. i updated with error

Comment: Please post full error with complete log.

Comment: Hi pavan, i updated the post. is that what you're looking for?

Comment: I noticed this line is giving me problems in the show view. its the delete action: <p><%= link_to "delete comment", game_review_path(review.game_id), method: :delete  %></p>

Answer (score 0):

I think the error is happening here: `edit_game_path`

Edit path requires a model id to work, so you need to pass it:

```
edit_game_path(@game)
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to change this line in your `show.html.erb`

```
<%= link_to "delete comment", game_review_path(review.game_id), method: :delete  %>
```

to

```
<%= link_to "delete comment", game_review_path(review, review.game_id), method: :delete  %>
```